Dependency Resolution In Android
Let's take a scenario.
I have an android application that has 2 dependencies.

dep_1:1.0.0
Okhttp:5.0.0

But the catch is, dep_1 also has okhttp:2.0.0 as it's dependency (api() instead of implementation() )
Now my question is after building the release apk, which version of okhttp will be packed??
And will the answer change if dep_1 uses implenentation() instead of api()?
Thanks!

I replaced [groovy] [kotlin] with [gradle], assuming, that this is the build tool your using. If not, tag with your choice accordingly.
